# datediff and dateadd anomaly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sede

What is the difference between the following two logic conditions (both CreationDate values are DateTime)?

```
   and abs(datediff(hour, a.CreationDate, e.CreationDate)) < 12
```

and:

```
   and e.CreationDate > dateadd(hour, -12, a.CreationDate)
   and e.CreationDate < dateadd(hour,  12, a.CreationDate)
```

(yes, there is a difference - the change produces different results, but I can't see what)

### Background

A recent [question came up on Meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256195/241497) about "curator" badges, and the 12-hour edit windows. That question inspired me to make a copy of an SQL query I had previously written, and to make the new copy "variable" sized edit windows, instead of just 12 hours each side. In essence, I changed the following code:

```
   and abs(datediff(hour, a.CreationDate, e.CreationDate)) < 12
```

to be:

```
   and e.CreationDate > dateadd(hour, -12, a.CreationDate)
   and e.CreationDate < dateadd(hour,  12, a.CreationDate)
```

(except the 12 values in the second statement are variables).

These two queries are in Stack Exchange Data Explorer: [original](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/232614/curator-badges) and [copied](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/312397/curators-with-variable-edit-window)

The queries produce slightly different results, though... and I am really scratching my head as to why. I also cannot decide which query result is correct. I believe it must come down to something in the datediff logic... does it 'round' hours up or something, so that it has slightly fewer results?

DateDiff:

[image]

DateAdd:

[image]

Comment: Can you print out the `CreationDate` values, sort by this and see which ones are missing? This might give you a clue as to what's happening.

Comment: I've also just run your queries and get 255 rows from each and the first few screens of results look identical.

Comment: The queries I linked have 255 results, but the first records have 288 questions on one, and 287 on the other.... is it a caching issue in SEDE presentation layer, perhaps, @ChrisF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DateDiff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) counts boundary crossings while [`DateAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) does straightforward arithmetic.

For example, the first query would count 12 boundaries between `00:59` and `12:01`, and would thus exclude that difference, but the second query would count it as being within 12 hours. This makes the second query 'right', and the first one 'wrong'.

Comment: Penny drops... yes. You mind if I edit your answer to include an example?

Comment: FYI -> referenced back [from Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256407/241497)